How do I specify php.ini settings (or a complete file) for Drush?
Before continuing, let me explain that I've tried the methods I've been able to find in documentation. Drush 12.5.2.0 is installed in the project by composer.
I've tried adding export DRUSH_INI='/Users/myusername/.drush/drush.ini' and export PHP_INI='/Users/myusername/.drush/php.ini' to my .zshrc file.
I've tried simply adding a drush.ini file to /Users/myusername/.drush and to /Sites/MAMP/foo/drush.
Drush is successfully finding drush.yml files in all the valid locations I've tried, but it seems to be ignoring every different attempt I've made to get it to find the php settings I want it to use. drush status continues to show the standard php.ini file is active, and when I try using a drush.ini file for overrides, the memory limit remains unchanged. It's working fine in every other respect.
What am I doing wrong here?

Stop making your life hard with MAMP, start using DDEV (or Lando or any other Docker-based PHP stack).

Which documentation? I second DDEV. Why suffer?


Before continuing, let me explain that I've tried the methods I've
been able to find in documentation.

The documentation you've read seems to be outdated. Current drush versions don't use *.ini files anymore. You can load additional php.ini files for CLI applications by exporting the shell variable PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR.
See https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Here I was looking at Drush documentation when the solution was in PHP documentation. Thank you!
